# How to pass additional arguments to my callback?

Tags: python, callback, ctypes

I have following simple example of a class where I define my callbacks:

```
api = CDLL('i:\\api.dll')
class CallBacks():
    def py_sessionCallback(aSessionHandle, aTag, aEvent):
        print ('Connection State Callback for session ' + str(aSessionHandle) + ':- Event - '  + aEvent)

     SESSIONCALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_int,c_void_p,c_int,c_char_p)
     sessionCallback = SESSIONCALLBACK(py_sessionCallback)

class CWrapper():
     RegisterSessionStateCallback = api.RegisterSessionStateCallback
     SW_RegisterSessionStateCallback.argtypes = [CallBacks.SESSIONCALLBACK]

class Session():
    def __init__(self,user,passw,timeout=120):
          self.server = c_char_p('https://test.con.com'.encode('utf-8')
          self.timeout = timeout
          self.dSessionCb = CallBacks.sessionCallback

    def __conCB(self):
          e = CWrapper.SW_RegisterSessionStateCallback(self.dSessionCb)
```

Now I want to modify the code in way that I pass `self.server` to my callback to achieve something like this:

```
class Session():
    .
    .
    .
    def __conCB(self):
          e = CWrapper.SW_RegisterSessionStateCallback(self.dSessionCb(**self.server**))

class CallBacks():
    def py_sessionCallback(aSessionHandle, aTag, aEvent,**server**):
        print (server + ': Connection State Callback for session ' + str(aSessionHandle) + ':- Event - '  + aEvent)
    .
    .
    .
```

Is there a way to transfer `self.server` to `py_sessionCallback`?
Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `py_object` as the type and pass anything you want to a callback.  Treat it as a `void*` in the C code.

You didn't provide a reproducible example, so here's a minimal one:

test.c:

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(const char* event, void* context);

CALLBACK g_callback;

API void register_callback(CALLBACK cb) {
    if(cb)
        g_callback = cb;
}

API void do_something(const char* event, void* context) {
    if(g_callback)
        g_callback(event,context);
}
```

test.py:

```py
from ctypes import *

CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(None,c_wchar_p,py_object)

@CALLBACK
def callback(event,obj):
    print(event,obj)

class Server:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Server(a={self.a})'

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.register_callback.argtypes = CALLBACK,
dll.register_callback.restype = None
dll.do_something.argtypes = c_wchar_p,py_object
dll.do_something.restype = None

dll.register_callback(callback)
s1 = Server(1)
s2 = Server(2)
dll.do_something('event1',s1)
dll.do_something('event2',s2)
```

Output:

```
event1 Server(a=1)
event2 Server(a=2)
```

Comment: Thank you vm for suggestion. If I understand it correctly, I need to modify C code and insert variable context of type void. Problem is I can not modify C code itself. Is there any other way how to "smuggle"  it inside?

Comment: @Dingo Possibly, but without seeing at least the C headers of the functions being dealt with I can't say.  It has to pass through the C code, so if the code doesn't ignore the pointer and just pass it along to the callback it's not likely.

Comment: this is what is in .h file: `CLIENT_API`
`ErrCode STDAPICALLTYPE ` `RegisterSessionStateCallback(SessionStateCallbackPtr cfunc);` `typedef void (STDAPICALLTYPE * SessionStateCallbackPtr)(SessionID sh, void* tag, ErrCode errorCode);`

Comment: I just realized, that there's actually a pointer in callback function `void* tag` in `(STDAPICALLTYPE * SessionStateCallbackPtr)(SessionID sh, void* tag, ErrCode errorCode)` which is specified in connector `ErrCode Connect(const char * server,int timeout, void * tag, SessionID * sh_out)`. Based on that I was able to pass required information, thanks to your code above which helped me to understand it. Many Thanks.

Comment: @Dingo I well-designed callback has a way to pass general information to the callback.  `void*` is the usual way for C++.  Good that your API has it.